# Method ArrayList.contains always return true

Tags: java, contains, hashcode, comparable, a-star

I'm a begignner java programmer implementing A* algorithm into a java code however it does not produce the desired result

To be specific I have class Grid

```
public class Grid implements Comparable<Grid> {

int depth=0;
public Tile [] [] puzzle= new Tile [SlidePuzzleModel.ROWS] [SlidePuzzleModel.COLS];
public static String [] [] goal= { {"","1","2","3"},{"4","5","6","7"},{"8","9","10","11"}, {"12","13","14","15"}};
private int unobserved;
private int cost;
```

My CompareTo method is as follows:

```
public int compareTo(Grid arg0) {
        Grid other = (Grid) (arg0);
        if (this.cost >= other.cost) {
            return 1;
        } else if (this.cost < other.cost) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

and my equlas is as follows:

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Grid other = (Grid) obj;
        if (!Arrays.deepEquals(this.puzzle, other.puzzle)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (this.depth != other.depth) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

my hash code function is as follows:

```
 @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 67 * hash + Arrays.deepHashCode(this.grid);
        return hash;
    }*/
```

The problem is that in my A* method I've created the closed list of type ArrayList() and I used method .contains however I don't know why it always returns true.
This is my calling statement

```
  public boolean Astar(Grid initialState)
  {
     PriorityQueue<Grid> fringe = new PriorityQueue<Grid>();
     List<Grid> closed = new ArrayList<Grid>();
     List<Grid> MyList; 
     boolean found=false;
     fringe.add(initialState);
     boolean contain;

   int count=0;
     while(fringe.isEmpty()==false && !found)// && !failure)
     {
         count++;
         System.out.println(" i is " +count);
         //get state from fringe    
        Grid current = fringe.poll();
        if(current.WaW(current))
        {  
            System.out.println("I am inside current.waw==true");
            found=true;
            break;

        }
       else
        {
         System.out.println("I am inside ELSE current.waw==true");
         contain=closed.contains(current);     
         if (contain==false)
       {  
         System.out.println("I am inside contain==false");               
         numOfNodeGenerated++;

           Grid nextState = current;
           //pos of empty tile
           int [] emptyPos=checkEmpty(nextState);

           MyList= moveTile (emptyPos[0], emptyPos[1]);
           System.out.println(";MyList.size() is "+ MyList.size());
           for (int i=0; i< MyList.size(); i++)
           {
                 System.out.println("I am inside My List Loop"); 
                 Grid gr=MyList.remove(i);
                 int hn=manhatten(gr);
                 int gn=numOfNodeGenerated-1;
                  gr.setCost(hn+gn); 

                  fringe.add(gr);

           }

       }
            closed.add(current);   
      }//END if
         //after expanding add it to closed



  }//end while
     System.out.println("I am out of the loop");
     return found;
  }
```

and the output I get is:
run:

```
4
 i is 1
I am inside ELSE current.waw==true
I am inside contain==false
4
;MyList.size() is 4
I am inside My List Loop
I am inside My List Loop
 i is 2
I am inside ELSE current.waw==true
 i is 3
I am inside ELSE current.waw==true
I am out of the loop
```

Comment: Can you show the full code, not only the "failing" test?

Comment: There is a dangling `*/` after your `hashCode()` method - did you probably comment out part of your code?

Comment: what is current here??I think your current variable is not being initialized correctly.

Comment: Please show more code, e.g where you fill the list `closed` and what is `current`. Btw, your `compareTo()` method will never return 0 because of the `>=`

Comment: @schwobaseggle I added the code